# SSD disk errors waking up from suspend

Tags: 20.04, suspend, dell, ssd, wakeup

The computer is a Dell Inspiron 15 16GB with SSD 512MB, running Ubuntu 20.04.  From time to time, when i put the computer to suspend, either closing the lid or selecting 'suspend' in the power off menu, i get tons of messages like "EXT4- fs error"  on the corresponding nvme device. It's like the SSD is not receiving a proper command or configuration, either at suspend time, either at wake up.  When the errors start they on the console screen, indefinitely, the computer gets very hot, and nothing is logged. Any hints on where i should look?[image]

Comment: That error is generally seen when a storage device does not have power. Are there any power-saving features in the BIOS that may be interfering with the OS? 

Comment: Please see my answer. If it helps resolve the errors, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score -1):

**File System**

Let's check/repair your broken file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p7`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Temperatures**

If you have a temp problem, that can directly effect the operation of the SSD or the computer. Install the gnome-shell extension `Freon`, found at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/841/freon/ and review the temps. Report back.

**SSD Firmware**

Check the firmware in your SSD.

If you have a Samsung SSD, go to https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/ and download their `Samsung Magician` software.

If you have a Dell SSD, go to https://www.dell.com and download their updater there.