# SSD disk not available after suspend on Zenbook

Tags: 20.04, suspend, ssd, asus

I use Kubuntu 20.04 (kernel 5.15.0-41) on an Asus Zenbook UX481F and have had no major issues (besides known problem with secondary touch screen).

Since last week, however, the computer is no longer usable after a suspend to RAM:

- machine wakes up and lets users log in past the lock screen, however
- the SSD (SAMSUNG MZVLB1T0HALR-00000) is no longer available and applications (and system) crash one after another whenever they try to access data on the disk.

I can for obvious reasons not supply a log from the failed wake-up, but the console fills with ext4-fs errors; the final entries to syslog before reboot are:

```
Jul 25 11:09:20 graffias systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Jul 25 11:09:20 graffias systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Jul 25 11:09:20 graffias systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Jul 25 11:09:20 graffias systemd-sleep[5275]: Suspending system...
Jul 25 11:09:20 graffias systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Succeeded.
Jul 25 11:09:20 graffias systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Jul 25 11:09:20 graffias kernel: [ 2083.871309] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Jul 25 11:09:20 graffias systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
^@^@^@(repeated ~ 100 times)
```

There is an [identical issue reported](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359728/ssd-disk-errors-waking-up-from-suspend) a year ago by user user259820, however there is no answer/solution posted.

Furthermore, I have encountered this issue in the past when using Kubuntu 22.04 right after it was released; reverting to 20.04 solved the problem, so it is probably not a damaged hardware issue (fsck and smartctl report no issues).

Lastly, I found an error description that was similar and suggested to add a kernel parameter 'iommu=soft'; this caused the machine to fail at boot due access errors to the SSD.

I really hope someone can help me (and user259830) to solve this conundrum!

Comment: Welcome to AU. Doesn't solve your problem, but worth using a live USB session to see if the live session can see / read the ssd - at least that'll help confirm it's not a hardware issue?

Comment: Thank you @will, I will try as soon as I return from my holidays (among other things I also forgot my USB stick ...).
However, I think I am coming closer to figuring out that it is a software problem, as returning to the previous kernel compiled with the previous linux-firmware seems to solve the issue. If anyone has a tip where to look, I would be very happy, because at the moment I am re-enacting the blind-man-in-a-dark-cellar routine in trying to figure out what exactly is going wrong.